# C wire contact missing at boiler

Tags: wiring, nest, adapter

I have a heat only system. My previous thermostat only use the red and white wire. The blue C wire was coiled up and unused. I purchased a new nest thermostat. Everything is wired fine at the thermostat however my boiler does not have a C wire connection. The red and white wires go to the thermostat screws on the aqua stat. Is it possible for me to connect the Blue c wire in the furnace room to some sort of transformer or adapter that plugs directly into the wall so I don't have to fish anything upstairs?

Comment: There have to be at least a dozen questions here asking basically the same thing, have you searched? Did you look at any of the "related" questions that came up when you were typing up your question?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at your boiler, as well as the make and model of the boiler, and any wiring diagrams posted there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Separate boiler and AC, to which does C wire connect for Nest thermostat](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/108488/separate-boiler-and-ac-to-which-does-c-wire-connect-for-nest-thermostat)

Answer (score 0):

often there is a terminal in the boiler where the c wire can be connected, but if not then yes a transformer can be added.

Comment: This answer is not very detailed. but then neither is the question.